# Can't check out code with subversion in netbeans?

Tags: svn, version-control, svn-checkout

This morning I commited some changes on my desktop, grabbed my laptop and headed out. Checked out code, programmed some more, and commited. Now I am back at home trying to check out my changes on the desktop PC and getting `"D:\foo\ is already a working copy for a different URL"`

How can I get my latest code?!

I have already deleted my local source and tried checking out again as I've seen recomended a few places. No luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to destroy everything, source files, netbeans project data (which I typically keep in a different folder), and a hidden folder called `/.svn/` that was in every sub folder and contained BASE.svn files.

Once I got rid of all of those I was able to download from my repository. I believe it may have worked if I simply got rid of the netbeans project data and the `/.svn/` folder.